# Can superoxide ion act as a ligand in a similar fashion as peroxide?

Tags: coordination-compounds, oxidation-state

There is a question in my chemistry book:

> Find oxidation state of platinum ion in the complex $\ce{[Pt(O2)(en)2Br]+}$.

My books says that there is peroxide, but I want to ask why it is peroxide? Can it be superoxide?

My answer was that oxidation state of platinum is $+3$, but the answer in the book given is $+4$ with explanation that $\ce{O2}$ here is *peroxide*. How can I get to know from the formula that $\ce{O2}$ is peroxide and not superoxide?

Comment: You don't know that from the formula alone.

Comment: Peroxide ligands are typically bridging ligands, I'd expect it to be a dinuclear complex at least. It  would be interesting to find out whether this standalone complex exists at all; if not, the textbook's question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC283438/pdf/pnas00102-0207.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0QEvUUW2WBHhbfzuO19u-Zx81eqw&nossl=1&oi=scholarr) the oxygen "molecule" in its complex with hemoglobin is rendered as a superoxide ligand.  But remember, electrons are shared between the metal and the ligand; so there may be some latitude in how you can apportion them to determine "oxidation states".